# worldpay setup with spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, spree, worldpay

I am trying to setup WorldPay with spree, I have created sandbox account also but could not found from where I found below details

INSTALLATION:
AMERICAN EXPRESS LOGIN:
DISCOVER LOGIN:
JCB LOGIN:
MASTERCARD LOGIN:
MAESTRO LOGIN:
VISA LOGIN:

please help if someone already setup this with the spree

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and my problem was that I was trying to integrate with Worldpay Online (not regular old Worldpay).

In the end I created my own gateway (very basic with only the options I needed, but you could extend this to add the functionality that you want):

```
class Spree::WorldpayOnlineGateway < Spree::Gateway

    preference :client_key, :string
    preference :service_key, :string

    def provider_class
        ActiveMerchant::Billing::WorldpayOnlinePaymentsGateway
    end

    def payment_source_class
        Spree::CreditCard
    end

    def purchase(money, credit_card, options = {})

      options[:client_key] = self.preferred_client_key
      options[:service_key] = self.preferred_service_key

      provider = provider_class.new(options)
      provider.purchase(money, credit_card, options)

    end

end
```

Then in your `spree.rb` initializer, add the gateway:

```
config = Rails.application.config
config.after_initialize do
     config.spree.payment_methods << Spree::WorldpayOnlineGateway
end
```